# how to access RAPL via perf with Rocket Lake?

Tags: x86, intel, perf, amd-processor, energy

I have a Rocket Lake CPU(11900K), but perf does not support access power events with it yet, how can I do it?

The perf events list:

pastebin.com + tcsSdxUx

My OS: Ubuntu 20.10 Kernel 5.12-RC6
perf version: 5.12-RC6

I can read the Rapl value with rapl-read.c (the link: [http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/rapl/](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/rapl/))

But rapl-read.c can not use to profiling the runing program. I hope to do profiling the runing program not only power events but also cycles, branch, etc., The SoCwatch from Intel can not do so much things.

Is there any way to add Rocket Lake power events support to perf ? I dont know the raw power events counter.

update #1:

the `uname -a` output:

Linux u128 5.12.0-051200rc6-generic #202104042231 SMP Sun Apr 4 22:33:57 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

update #2:
`rapl-read -m` output

```
RAPL read -- use -s for sysfs, -p for perf_event, -m for msr
```

Found RocketLake Processor type
0 (0), 1 (0), 2 (0), 3 (0), 4 (0), 5 (0), 6 (0), 7 (0)

```
    Detected 8 cores in 1 packages
```

Trying /dev/msr interface to gather results

```
    Listing paramaters for package #0
            Power units = 0.125W
            CPU Energy units = 0.00006104J
            DRAM Energy units = 0.00006104J
            Time units = 0.00097656s

            Package thermal spec: 125.000W
            Package minimum power: 0.000W
            Package maximum power: 0.000W
            Package maximum time window: 0.000000s
            Package power limits are unlocked
            Package power limit #1: 4095.875W for 0.108398s (enabled, not_clamped)
            Package power limit #2: 4095.875W for 0.032227s (disabled, not_clamped)
    PowerPlane1 (on-core GPU if avail) 0 policy: 16


    Sleeping 1 second

    Package 0:
            Package energy: 62.846985J
            PowerPlane0 (cores): 45.371277J
            PowerPlane1 (on-core GPU if avail): 0.000000 J
            DRAM: 0.000000J
            PSYS: -0.000000J
```

Note: the energy measurements can overflow in 60s or so
so try to sample the counters more often than that.

Update #3:
I found it is hard to simple use rapl msr to get the whole power consumption:

```
ujtoj=1000000;
bgn_energy=$(rdmsr -d 0x611);
time sh doit.sh;
end_energy=$(rdmsr -d 0x611);
printf '%.3f\n' "$(((end_energy - bgn_energy)/ujtoj))e-3"
```

Output:

```
real    2m58.411s
user    2m58.068s
sys     0m0.168s
0.197
```

The doit.sh is a shell script to run SPEC CPU2017 500.perlbench test. For Zen 3, the energy consumption(power/energy_pkg) from perf stat output is about 7486.61J, much higher than "0.197" which output from simple use rdmsr.

update #4:
Now I had found another way to solve my problem.
It is easy to add RKL support by add some "#define" and "case:" code.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPU name:   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900K @ 3.50GHz
CPU type:   Intel Rocketlake processor
CPU clock:  3.50 GHz
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group 1: ENERGY
+-----------------------+---------+--------------+
|         Event         | Counter |  HWThread 6  |
+-----------------------+---------+--------------+
|   INSTR_RETIRED_ANY   |  FIXC0  | 996795747147 |
| CPU_CLK_UNHALTED_CORE |  FIXC1  | 321084408076 |
|  CPU_CLK_UNHALTED_REF |  FIXC2  | 216809163858 |
|       TEMP_CORE       |   TMP0  |           65 |
|     PWR_PKG_ENERGY    |   PWR0  |    4050.2952 |
|     PWR_PP0_ENERGY    |   PWR1  |    2982.4675 |
|    PWR_DRAM_ENERGY    |   PWR3  |            0 |
+-----------------------+---------+--------------+
+----------------------+------------+
|        Metric        | HWThread 6 |
+----------------------+------------+
|  Runtime (RDTSC) [s] |    62.0025 |
| Runtime unhalted [s] |    91.6329 |
|      Clock [MHz]     |  5189.3093 |
|          CPI         |     0.3221 |
|    Temperature [C]   |         65 |
|      Energy [J]      |  4050.2952 |
|       Power [W]      |    65.3247 |
|    Energy PP0 [J]    |  2982.4675 |
|     Power PP0 [W]    |    48.1024 |
|    Energy DRAM [J]   |          0 |
|    Power DRAM [W]    |          0 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Does the ocperf.py wrapper for perf (from https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) work?  Before mainline perf got event names for things like `uops_issued.any`, I used to use ocperf.py to get symbolic event names.

Comment: pmu-tools does not support rocket lake yet. 
./ocperf.py
Downloading https://download.01.org/perfmon/mapfile.csv to mapfile.csv
Do not recognize CPU or cannot find CPU map file.

Still missing power/energy events.

Comment: Oh well, was worth a try.  That might get updated before mainline perf; worth trying again sometime.  As far as "any way to add Rocket Lake power events", well perf is open source.  If you have some time to spend on this, you could dig in and find Intel documentation and add support yourself, and send in a patch or pull request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the RKL core and uncore perf events were added in v5.11-rc1 and the RAPL-based powercap support was added in v5.9-rc5, the RAPL perf PMU is not yet supported, not even in the latest 5.15.1 kernel version. The RAPL PMU is also not yet supported for TGL, TNT, and LKF. This looks strange to me because it seems that the ADL and SPR RAPL PMUs are already supported. Did they just forget to add support for these other processors? Anyway, you have to use other tools for now.

Note that for the core PMU events, the perf_event subsystem lets you only use the architectural events if it's running on an unsupported processor model. But you can still use the raw event encoding as documented in the perf man pages. This approach is only reliable for events without constraints because `perf_event` isn't aware of any constraints that may exist on an unsupported model. Most events don't have constraints, so this isn't a major problem.

I don't know why you think that `rapl-read` can't be used to profile a program. There is no program-specific or core-specific RAPL domains. You can run `rapl-read` with the `-m` option to directly access MSRs to take energy readings, then your program, then run `rapl-read` again. The difference between the two readings gives you energy consumption for each of the supported domains. Note that you've to modify the `rapl_msr()` function so that it invokes your program between the readings instead of just doing `sleep(1)`. Otherwise, it'll just report the energy consumption in about a second with hardly any correlation of the energy consumption of your program.

`rapl-read` doesn't currently support RKL (or any of the very recent Intel processors). But you can easily add RAPL support by first determining the CPU model from `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and then adding a macro definition like `#define CPU_ROCKETLAKE model` similar to the currently supported models. I see only two switch statements on the CPU mode, one in `detect_cpu(void)` and one in `rapl_msr(int core, int cpu_model)`. Just add a case for `CPU_ROCKETLAKE`. RKL has the same RAPL domains as SKL, so place together with `CPU_SKYLAKE` in both functions. That should do it. Or you can avoid `rapl-read` altogether and just use `wrmsr` and `rdmsr` in a shell script that takes readings, runs the program, and then takes readings again.

MSR 0x611 is `MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS`, which reports a 32-bit unsigned value. The unit of this value is `MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT` and the default is 15.26uj. You seem to think it's in micro-joules. Are you sure that this is what `MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT` says? Even then, the result of the expression `$(((end_energy - bgn_energy)/ujtoj))e-3` is in kilo-joules, so how are you comparing it with `power/energy_pkg` on Zen3, which is clearly in joules?

If the correct unit is 15.26uj, then the measurement on the Intel processor would be 15.26*197000000 = 3,009,226,220,000 joules (about 3000 gigajoules). But since only the lowest 32 bits of the MSR register are valid, the maximum value is 15.26*(2^32 - 1) = 65,541,200,921.7 joules (about 65 gigajoules). So I think the unit is not 15.26uj.

It seems that the `500.perlbench` benchmark with the `test` input took about 3 minutes to complete. It's hard to know whether `MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS` has wrapped around or not because the reported number is not negative.

I think it's better to run `500.perlbench` on one core and then run a script on another core that reads `MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS` every few seconds. For example, you can put `rdmsr -d 0x611` in a loop and sleep for some number of seconds in each iteration. Since `500.perlbench` takes a relatively long time to complete, you don't have to start both programs at precisely the same time. In this way, you'd mimic the way `perf stat -a -I 1000 -e power/energy-pkg/` works had the event `power/energy-pkg/` been supported on your kernel on the Intel platform.

I've discussed the reliability of Intel's RAPL-based energy measurements at: [perf power consumption measure: How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956287/perf-power-consumption-measure-how-does-it-work). However, I don't know if anyone has validated the accuracy of AMD's RAPL. It's unclear to me to what extent a comparison between Intel's `MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS` and AMD's `Core::X86::Msr::PKG_ENERGY_STAT` is meaningful.

Comment: I had update the kernel to 5.12-rc6 ( I just add the uname -a output in the question).

Comment: rapl-read -m output:
Unsupported CPU model -1
Unable to read RAPL counters.

The meaning of use rapl-read to profilng a running program is that  I can not use the below command to do a energy profiling(a SPEC CPU 2017 sub-test):

rapl ../run_base_refrate_icc.0000/bwaves_r_base.icc bwaves_1 < bwaves_1.in

the rapl-read only output the value of sleep 1s.

Comment: @EdisonChan Have made the changes I told you about? Show the entire code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. my mistake(I forgot the bin file name was changed). Rapl-read can use -m to to the rapl value of RKL now, but I still dont know how to use it to get the average power of a program in its total lifetime( I have add the output of rapl-read -m in the question).

Comment: I found the rdmsr way maybe not suitable for the program that use high energy and the liftime over 60 seconds. According Intel SDM: "It has a wraparound time of around 60 secs when power consumption is high, and may be longer otherwise."

Comment: Thanks,Hadi. I am not very familiar with use expression to do float point compute, now I found use "bc" will be better (bc  <<< "end_energy - bgn_energy)/ujtoj"). The overflow problem of  MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS with simple use rdmsr is some kind hard to me, but I had find a better way to solve my problem: likwid-perfctf. TomTheBear， the maintainer of likwid told me how to add RKL support in likwid, it works so far.